# Give different collections in solrCloud their own set of configs

Tags: solr, solrcloud

I currently have solrCloud up an running, with a few cores that I copied from other solr instances (with the data removed of course).

I was trying to figure out why the dataImportHandler that exists in the coreName/conf directory is not getting used when I created a new core (to a new collection) an realized that it had not created a conf folder at all, and was just using the "root" one that was already there (for collection1).

How can I change this?

Currently, I start solrCloud with:
`java -DzkRun -DnumShards=2 -Dbootstrap_confdir=./solr/collection1/conf -Dcollection.configName=myconf -jar start.jar`

Which I suspect might be the problem (this is from the example that can be found in `solr/example`) i.e. that I have hardcoded a config for each core. I therefore tried `java -DzkRun -DnumShards=2 -jar start.jar` but met with the same issue.

How can I define settings on a collection or core basis (collection would be more useful) in solrCloud?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have 2 different configurations, you should upload configurations to the zookeeper using zkCli as described on SolrCloud wiki page. You can create collections via Collections API (https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Collections+API); you should wire  collection with configuration by using config name in API call. Then you can assign core to collection either via solr.xml or via the solr admin UI. Hope this helps.